# docker container timezone is not propagated

Tags: docker, timezone

I am not able to propagate host's timezone to the container, whatever way I try it.
Please advise:

```
$:~/$ cat /etc/timezone
Asia/Jerusalem
$:~/$ date
Sun Feb  2 13:50:02 IST 2020 # TIME ON HOST (correct)
$:~/$ docker run --rm -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro -v 
/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro -e TZ=`cat /etc/timezone` ubuntu date
Sun Feb  2 11:50:08 Asia 2020 # TIME ON THE CONTAINER (wrong)
```

As you can see, the timezone of the container is wrong and the time is always UTC.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that -e TZ=`cat /etc/timezone` option actually breaks things. I've just removed this parameter and it works well now:

```
docker run --rm -v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro ubuntu date
```

Note: it is working for **ubuntu** and **alpine** containers. For **busybox**, it is still not.

Answer (score 0):

Just mounting the `/etc/localtime` in readonly mode in enough to set time inside the container.

```
docker run --rm -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro busybox date
```

**Output**

```
Sun Feb  2 21:26:54 IST 2020
```

Comment: it is not enough

    $ docker run --rm -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro busybox date
    Mon Feb  3 09:41:53 UTC 2020
    $ date
    Mon Feb  3 11:42:03 IST 2020

Comment: @Moisei I have docker installed on ubuntu 16.04 and it works perfectly for centos7, ubuntu, apline and busybox containers. On which OS have you installed docker?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use an image that includs `tzdata` package to use `TZ` environment variable. 
For example, define dockerfile like following:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata
```

Build your own image:

```sh
docker build -t my_image .
```

Then it's possble to set local time within container by passing `TZ` variable.

```sh
docker run --rm -e TZ=Asia/Jerusalem my_image date
```

Comment: it is not needed. also managing a custom Docker files would be a mess.

Comment: @Moisei, it's not necessary to manage  Docker files. You could store resulting image within your registry and then use as base image.